# Counting average grades

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

in December I started working with Python and due to personal problems I cannot give it as much attention as I thought I could. I need help with my first basic project. I need to write a program that let's it's user write number of school grades and counts the average. I can start, write a list of grades but i cannot type a code that would count the average. I guess my problem lies in some basic knowledge which I lack of. I'd appreciate every help guys.

EDIT:

```
assignments = 5

x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in     range(assignments)]


finalGrade = int(input('Ocena z kolokwium: '))

average_assignment_grade = (sum(x) + finalGrade) / 6

print()
print('Średnia')


for number in range(1):
    print(format(average_assignment_grade, '.1f'))

A.append(average_assignment_grade);



grades_sum = sum(A)
grades_average = grades_sum / 6
if grades_sum < 3 print ("Przedmiot nie zaliczony")
else print("Przedmiot zaliczony")
File "<ipython-input-43-fe40b7e5825c>", line 23
if grades_sum < 3 print ("Przedmiot nie zaliczony")
```

So this is the code. As you can see I wanted it to show if the student has passed or not (it's in polish, "Przedmiot nie zaliczony" - not passed, "Przedmiot zaliczony" - passed) but I got invalid syntax error. I looked up my notes and I did everything like they say but obviously something is wrong and I have no idea what. Can you help now?

Comment: Just define a list `listname = []` and use a loop for input to append the scores into the list, then do something like `average = sum(listname)/len(listname)`. That's one easy way to do it.

Comment: Hi! SO is a bit more about helping to troubleshoot issues with code that has already been written to increase understanding. It isn't really about writing code from scratch. This might be an okay place to start your learning! https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-pandas/how-to-get-average-of-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Google search will show examples of averaging grades such as [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176762/get-average-grade-for-10-students-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176762/get-average-grade-for-10-students-python)

Answer (score 1):

I have spotted 3 errors in your code and corrected them. 2 of them is indentation error(Error2 and Error3) and one of them is because you have not declared list before using it(Error1).

```
assignments = 5
x = [int(input('Ocena z cwiczenia {}: '.format(i+1))) for i in range(assignments)]

finalGrade = int(input('Ocena z kolokwium: '))

average_assignment_grade = (sum(x) + finalGrade) / 6

print()
print('Średnia')

for number in range(1):
    print(format(average_assignment_grade, '.1f'))

#error1 Before calling predefined function of list, you need to declare a list.
A = []
A.append(average_assignment_grade)



grades_sum = sum(A)
grades_average = grades_sum / 6

#Error2 In python, indentation is important. Scope of all conditional statements is 
#determine by indentation block.
if grades_sum < 3 : #Error2
    print ("Przedmiot nie zaliczony")
else: #Error3
    print("Przedmiot zaliczony")
```

Hope it solves your problem.